# C# .NET замена содержимого блока <div>

Tags: c#, .net

К примеру у нас имеется div.reklama ,а в нем картинка 
Как с помощью HttpListener или чего-то другого изменить содержимое div.reklama ?

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Напишите простыми словами где находится div и какой ожидается результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить элемент через GetElementById(string el)
или получить коллекцию через GetElementsByTagName(string el)
Далее использовать свойства InnerHtml. Это если страница загружается через WebBrowser или аналоги. webbrowser.Document....

Если страница получена в результате get/post запроса, то это string, там уж проще использовать Regex.